# How to calculate data when a data pass to another activity on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

i want to calculate a data in Main2activity.java, which is the data is from Mainactivity.java. I pass data "kaloriseminggu" from Mainactivity.java to Main2activity.java and i want to calculate "kaloriseminggu" divided to 7000, but when i run my app, it stop working. Can someone help me?

Mainactivity.java

```
package stmikbumigoramataram.simulasipemodelan;

import android.content.Intent; 
import android.provider.ContactsContract; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.EditText; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView ttkalorisehari, ttkaloriseminggu,txtbb;
    int naik_bb,nilai_bb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
        ttkalorisehari = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tjml_kal);
        ttkaloriseminggu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tjml_kal_seminggu);
        txtbb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tnaik_bb);

       //naik_bb = Integer.valueOf(ttkaloriseminggu.getText().toString());
        ttkalorisehari.setText(data.getString("kalorisehari"));
        ttkaloriseminggu.setText(data.getString("kaloriseminggu"));

        try {
            nilai_bb = Integer.valueOf(data.getString("kaloriseminggu"));
            naik_bb = nilai_bb/7000;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

}
```

Main2activity.java

```
package stmikbumigoramataram.simulasipemodelan;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.renderscript.Double2;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView ttkalorisehari, ttkaloriseminggu,txtbb;
    double naik_bb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
    ttkalorisehari = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tjml_kal);
    ttkaloriseminggu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tjml_kal_seminggu);
    txtbb = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tnaik_bb);

   //naik_bb = Integer.valueOf(ttkaloriseminggu.getText().toString());
    ttkalorisehari.setText(data.getString("kalorisehari"));
    ttkaloriseminggu.setText(data.getString("kaloriseminggu"));

    try {
        double nilai_bb = Double.parseDouble(ttkaloriseminggu.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        naik_bb = (Double.valueOf(nilai_bb)/7000);
        txtbb.setText(df.format(naik_bb));
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


  }

}
```

Comment: both of your activities are same . . . check one more time

Comment: You've added MainActivity2 twice. Can you please update and replace the first one by the appropriated MainActivity code?

Comment: dude.. they both are Main2Activity .. check it and upload logacat too

Comment: u drunk? or it is the activity with different name?

Comment: Im sorry guys, ill edit it later